# vb.net - linq - filtering list object 

Tags: vb.net

I am using LINQ - VB.Net

I want to filter my List object by passing String object in the where.

```
Dim _permittedTransactionCodes As List(Of String) = Nothing   'String object
```

it is populated with data.

```
Dim tap100transCodeInfos As List(Of Tap100transCodeInfo) = _dal.GetActiveTap100transCodeByHdrScreenCde(UCase(screenId), "TRAN_CDE")
```

i am trying something below, but not getting the filtered results

```
tap100transCodeInfos.Where(Function(x) _permittedTransactionCodes.Contains(x.TranCde))
```

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to assign the output of the `Where` function to a variable.  `Where` does not filter the existing list, but returns a new filtered list.

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Tap100transCodeInfo) = _
    tap100transCodeInfos.Where(Function(x) _
        _permittedTransactionCodes.Contains(x.TranCde) _
    )
```

Then `result` should have the filtered results.

**EDIT:**

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)` so if you are assigning the output to the same variable you need to append `.ToList()` to the end of the statement (or define `tap100transCodeInfos` to be an `IEnumerable(Of Tap100transCodeInfo)` from the start).

```
tap100transCodeInfos = _
    tap100transCodeInfos.Where(Function(x) _
        _permittedTransactionCodes.Contains(x.TranCde) _
    ).ToList()
```

Comment: "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[RTS.BusinessEntities.Tap100transCodeInfo]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[RTS.BusinessEntities.Tap100transCodeInfo]'."

Comment: @user706311 added an addendum.